# PhpStorm, file type contain multiple coding languages

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way within PhpStorm that I can assign a `*.tpl` file as it's **Smarty** type but also a **Vue** file, as it does contain Vue code and it would be nice to have the `{{ variable }}` recognized.

[image]

Comment: Try `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Template Data Languages` -- there you can use some another language instead of default HTML. So it still will be a Smarty with another language instead of HTML.

Comment: You have to apply that to the entire project rather than a certain file type?

Comment: Template Data Languages can be applied to a folder or specific file.